# finding the sum of corners in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have a parallelogram ABCD and a dot P lying somewhere in it (which means dot P belongs to the parallelogram, lies on the same plane).

Now I fold too opposite corners of the parallelogram in such a way that their angular points are placed exactly on the point P, like shown here:

[image]

If we know that angle B is equal to 50 degrees and the angle EPH is equal to 110 degrees, how can I find the the sum of angles PFC and PGC?

Can anybody give me some directions, please?

Comment: Have you tried marking the diagram with all the angles you know? A bit of angle-chasing is all that’s needed.

Comment: @DavidQuinn - What do you mean by "angle-chasing"?

Comment: Filling in any missing angles using the data you already have…

Comment: @DavidQuinn - I know that angle A is equal to angle C and that angle B is equal to angle D, but I don't know how I can benefit from that in this particular task.

Comment: And you know three of the angles at P

Comment: @DavidQuinn - Ah! I got your hint. 360 minus those three angles, right?

Comment: @DavidQuinn So, if I got your hint right, I can find the value of angle FPG = 360 - 50 - 50 - 110 = 150. But what's then? How will that help me find the sum of PFC and PGC? After all, angle FPG is not necessarily equal to the angle FCG because FPGC doesn't look to be a parallelogram.

Comment: @DavidQuinn - Ah, I think you also mean that I can find the value of angle C (C = 360 - angle B - angle C = 360 - 50 -50 = 260) and that, knowing that, I can find the sum of PFC and PGC in a similar way (angle PFC + angle PGC = 360 - angle FPG - angle C), right?

Comment: As you said, angle C should be equal to angle A (not $260$)

Comment: @Patricio - Yes, I see it should be divided by 2 first, which means angle A = angle C = 260/2 = 130. Well, it looks like, know that, my task is solved, but I am a bit confused by this: how can I be sure that angle B is equal to angle EPF and that angle D is equal to angle HPG in the first place?

Comment: Because you are just folding the appropriate corner. You're not modifying angles B or D

Comment: @Patricio - Ah, I see. Thank you!